# Rails when to avoid database

Tags: database, architecture

#### how big a data is too big to go into a database?

If optimised, database access can be faster than simple file system access.

But assuming the server is running on either:

- a conventional budget home server
- AWS

Is there any reason to use database for storing things larger than some articles?

The power of X-sendfile made me decide to move some data to the filesystem, but to what extent should I do this?

Comment: You can't search in the file contents [as efficiently]. Especially if the files are on S3. That's when you should _not_ avoid database.

Comment: Without any concrete examples of what you're talking about it's impossible to provide general advice. Also the term "database" is pretty broad--ElasticSearch is a database and is pretty good at indexing large textual documents. What specifically are you talking about?

Comment: This really has nothing to do with rails.

Comment: I see. Thanks Sergio. Now I know when I should use database. Dave, you are right. What I got are multimedia files/videos. Right now I'm writing a simple WebApp where users can post a video/audio file and ask questions about it. But my question really boils down to  "should every file be served by web server rather than by rails when if it can be done so?" and about when the cost of generating files and managing them cease to be rewarding.

Comment: @Iceman To think about it, yes it's not only rails. But what should be the tag for this? I mean deciding when to generate files and let web server deliver them is still part of writing a web app, although not rails specific.

Answer (score 0):

The only data I wouldn't store on a database are files.

Files whose content I do not need to search.

Like images, videos etc.

Any other data, regardless of the size will go into a database.

If I have a JSON file it will go into a NoSQL database that can search and index JSON file.

If I have a Gigabytes of data on anything, anything at all it will go into a database.

Databases have much better mechanisms than anything anyone can rig for files in a filesystem.

You question lacks context for me to give a better answer.